# Command 'blender' not found, despite executing from the installed directory

Tags: python, blender

I am trying to execute a python file using the python from blender. I have downloaded and placed the blender inside my user's home directory. But everytime I try to execute blender command I get the following error:

```
Command blender not found, but can be installed with:
sudo snap install blender  # version 2.79b, or
sudo apt  install blender
See 'snap info blender' for additional versions.`
```

My current directory is:

`$ pwd
/home/rishik/Applications/blender-2.79b-linux-glibc219-x86_64`

I executed the following:

`blender --background python somepythonfile.py`

I do not understand how to invoke python from blender now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux (by default) doesn't put the current working directory in the search `PATH`. If your blender directory is not in `PATH`, then you need to specify a full path, even for the current directory:

`./blender --background python somepythonfile.py`

You can add `.` to the search path, but this is considered a bad idea due to the possibility of malware impersonating a common command (like `ls`).

Comment: such a foolish mistake, spent hours on this. Thank you very much.